# Xcode .dae scene not loading up

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, collada

Hello i am trying to import *COLLADA* 3d model into my application. So i tried using only the story board for this job but now i have everything working except my model is not displayed. I have opened a GLKIT view panel with scene kit inside it which is said to load my *COLLADA* scene but every time i run the app i just see the background of the Simulation and nothing inside the window. What should i do in order to get my 3d model displayed??? Please help.